# Is anyone really convinced of ANT + technology/benefits?

Tags: bike-computer

I want to replace a computer with a new one (triple wireless) cadence, HR and speed but am in two minds as to if I should get a comp with ANT+. They seem more expensive and for what I will use it for, I don't need the connection to an app/computer. 
Comments?

Comment: This seems to be completely opinion based, which is not really a good fit for the SE format.

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.SE] Jen. Currently your question is seeking opinions, which is not a fit for the site rules - see the [help]. Perhaps you can edit your post so that is asks a more fact-based question, what would have a more definitive answer.

Comment: ANT+ is absolutely what you should choose. Bluetooth doesn't work when the signal has to pass through the human body, which means your device and its receiver must be on the same side of your body.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely go for ANT+. If a sensor packs up, it's much easier to replace it if it uses ANT+ rather than a proprietary protocol. If you want to upgrade anytime soon (to get GPS etc) you only have to replace the head unit. If decide you want to track your rides on Strava/ridewithGPS etc you can connect to many new phones (mainly Samsung and Sony). Well worth it.

You can get something like the Cateye Stealth 50 for not much more than any other wireless computer.